# How can I calculate date with datepicker in swift

Tags: iphone, swift3

(First of all, I am sorry to say that, I am not good at English)

Hi. I make an application in swift3.

I want to calculate date that was from datepicker and date of today.

I don't have any idea that how can I make date from datepicker be a format that is able to calculate.

```
    @IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let date = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: datePicker.date, dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .none)
    dateField.text = date

}
```

This code save date and show date. When I click the button, the date save in label.

I can't calculate with that formate. I don't know how to get (today - date)

What can I do?

Comment: what do you want to _calculate_? what do you need to _calculate_?

Comment: You can use date method timeIntervalSinceDate or simply date.timeIntervalSinceNow

Comment: If you need to display the date components and don't need the seconds just use DateComponentsFormatter

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to calculate the gap between today and selected date picker date in months or years or days??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming your function is the @IBOutlet to your UIDatePicker and I guess you want to calculate time interval between the date/time you pick from the picker and Now.

```
 @IBAction func datePickerPicked(_ sender: Any) {

      if let value = (sender as! UIDatePicker).date as Date? {

         // How many seconds between the picker's value to present time
         var secondsInterval = Int(value.timeIntervalSinceNow)

         let text = secondsInterval < 0 ? "in the PAST" : "in the FUTURE"

         // Remove negative sign, conversion
         secondsInterval = abs(secondsInterval)
         let days = secondsInterval / (60 * 60 * 24)
         let hrs = secondsInterval / (60 * 60)
         let mins = (secondsInterval % 3600) / 60
         let seconds = secondsInterval % 60

         print("You have picked: " ,days, "days,", hrs, "hours,", mins, "mins,", seconds, "seconds", text)
      }
   }
```